# Permalinks not working after Migration – AllowOverride All, htaccess set

Tags: permalinks, migration

I'm at my wits end, I migrated a website onto a different server and after a lot of setting up I finally have it where it works – kinda. The Permalinks are broken and throw errors that the site can't be found.

Inside the httpd.conf I set the right (I think) settings:

```
<Directory /opt/wordpress>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The htaccess is there and writeable by WP

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I can't seem to get them to work, all searching left me at this dead end. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The server is running Apache on CentOS, running PHP7 if that matters somehow.

Comment: Did you change the domain name? Did you copy all assets (including the uploads folder where all media is stored)? Did you follow standard guidance on moving a site (see the Codex)?

Answer (score -1):

I feel stupid but I didn't realize the httpd.conf loads another config at a later point where it was configured to override AllowOverride again. Changed it there to All and it worked, thank you!